# send eth transaction from one address to another with web3py

Tags: web3.py, infura

I want to send 1 ETH from one account to another with web3.py, however the transaction does not appear on chain after the standard timeout of 2 minutes.

```
from web3 import Web3
from web3.auto.infura import w3
import os

def connect(network):
    if network == "kovan":
        infura_kovan_url = "https://kovan.infura.io/v3/my_project_url"
        web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_kovan_url))
        chain_id = 42
        print("connected to kovan network:", web3.isConnected())
    elif network == "ropsten":
        infura_ropsten_url = "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/my_project_url"
        web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_ropsten_url))
        chain_id = 3
        print("connected to ropsten network:", web3.isConnected())
    return web3, chain_id

def send_transaction(connection, from_address, to_address, value, chain_id):
    transaction = {
        'from': from_address,
        'to': to_address,
        'value': value,
        'gas': 1000000,
        'gasPrice': w3.toWei('150','gwei'),
        'nonce': connection.eth.getTransactionCount(from_address) + 1,
        'chainId': chain_id
    }

    signed_transaction = connection.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key=os.environ['PRIVATE_KEY'])
    tx_hash = connection.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_transaction.rawTransaction)
    return tx_hash


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # connection, chain_id = connect("kovan")
    connection, chain_id = connect("ropsten")
    from_address = "0xabc..."
    to_address = "0x123..."

    # balance of source before transaction
    print(f"current balance: {w3.fromWei(connection.eth.getBalance(from_address), 'ether')} ether")
    print(f"transaction count: {connection.eth.getTransactionCount(from_address)}")

    value = w3.toWei(1, "ether")
    tx_hash = send_transaction(connection, from_address, to_address, value, chain_id)

    receipt = connection.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash) # timeout here
    print(receipt)

    # balance of source after transaction
    print(f"current balance: {w3.fromWei(connection.eth.getBalance(from_address), 'ether')} ether")
```

My from_address has 5/10 ETH on the kovan/ropsten networks. connection.eth.getTransactionCount(from_address) returns 0 (I have not made any successful transactions). I have tried with other nonces. My infura project url is set as an environment variable.

Possible duplicate to [Infura not broadcasting my transactions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/56179/infura-not-broadcasting-my-transactions), however I also tried increasing the gas_price and gas_limit until I hit the block gas limit.

Comment: You should set nonce to `connection.eth.getTransactionCount(from_address)` without the `+1`.

Comment: Yes, this worked.

The reason is that all of the transactions with lower level nonces need to be processed first, starting with the 0 nonce. It's a zero-based counter.